# Applications of polylogarithmic functors?

Tags: real-analysis

I read in Stein's monograph that polylogarithmic functors have been used as models for chaos in two- and three-dimensional Hilbert spaces.  So it seems natural to apply them to more general spaces--e.g., complex n-manifolds.  I was wondering if there has been any research in this area, and if so, could you perhaps direct me to some papers? Thanks.